# How to use Angular Datatables with Django Backend

Tags: django, angular, datatables

I'm trying to use Datables with Django but I couldn't figure out how to get data in the correct form. Django's rest API is returning an object but the Angular Datatables want a JSON file, so how can I achieve this result?

Here's what I've tried:

HTML:

```
<table datatable class="row-border hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th class="date">Id</th>
                    <th class="date">Nom</th>
                    <th class="societe">Email</th>
                    <th class="evenements">Date d'inscription</th>
                    <th class="facturePDF">Actif</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngIf="persons?.length != 0">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of Users;let index=index">
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.name}} {{item?.lastname}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.email}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.date_joined.slice(0,10)}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.is_active}}
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody *ngIf="Users?.length == 0">
                <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
        </table>
```

admin.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 2
    };
    this.GetUsers();
  }

GetUsers(){
    this.ApiService.list_users(this.page).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.Users = this.Users.concat(data);
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

The "list_users" function call Django to retrieve data from the database:

````
@api_view(['GET','POST','DELETE'])  
def list_annonces(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        annonces = Annonces.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        count = Annonces.objects.count()
        try:
            page = int(request.GET.get('page'))
        except Exception:
            page = 1
        limit = count
        offset = (page-1) * 10
        annonces_data = AnnonceSerialize(annonces.all()[offset:limit], many=True)
        return Response(annonces_data.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```
````

Comment: Have you tried parsing the object to be able to read it as JSON?

Comment: Can you suggest some code to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if anyone is facing the same problem, here's how I fixed it:

in you component file add this code:

```
class Person {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  persons: Person[];
  private dtTrigger: Subject<Users> = new Subject();

 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private ApiService : ApiService,
    private Authservice: AuthService, private approuter: Router, private MatDialog : MatDialog,
    private config: ConfigService, private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10
    };
    this.http.get<any>(this.Authservice.getApiUrl() + 'users/list/?page=1')
      .subscribe(persons => {
        this.persons = persons;
        console.log("Persons == ", this.persons);
        // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

For the template file, I need to iterate over the new persons object instead of the User array:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                    <th class="date">Id</th>
                    <th class="date">Nom</th>
                    <th class="societe">Email</th>
                    <th class="evenements">Date d'inscription</th>
                    <th class="facturePDF">Actif</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngIf="persons?.length != 0">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of persons;let index=index">
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.name}} {{item?.lastname}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.email}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.date_joined.slice(0,10)}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-monospace pt-3 pl-4">
                        {{item?.is_active}}
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody *ngIf="persons?.length == 0">
                <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to `JSON.stringify(<object_from_django>)`.